# Spring restTemplate get raw json string

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

How can I get the raw json string from spring rest template? I have tried following code but it returns me json without quotes which causes other issues, how can i get the json as is.

```
ResponseEntity<Object> response  = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Object.class);
String json = response.getBody().toString();
```

Comment: can you put the example print out?

Comment: have you tried to use `String`? `restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You don't even need `ResponseEntity`s! Just use [`getForObject`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForObject-java.net.URI-java.lang.Class-) with a `String.class` like:

```
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
final String response = restTemplate.getForObject("https://httpbin.org/ip", String.class);

System.out.println(response);
```

It will print something like:

```
{
  "origin": "1.2.3.4"
}
```

Comment: My return type is object and I want the raw json string?

Comment: this won't wotk when the server sends `application/json` as content type `Cannot deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token` it will only gibt you a string if the body just contains a json-string

Comment: new implementations of Spring no longer work when contentType is application/json so you can use java.util.LinkedHashMap as response object and will convert Json to a map

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `restTemplate.execute` and pass `ResponseExtractor` that just parses the `InputStream` from the body.

```java
public <T> T execute(String url,
    org.springframework.http.HttpMethod method,
    org.springframework.web.client.RequestCallback requestCallback,
    org.springframework.web.client.ResponseExtractor<T> responseExtractor,
    Object... uriVariables )
```

For example:

```java
String rawJson = restTemplate.execute(url, HttpMethod.GET, (clientHttpRequest) -> {}, this::responseExtractor, uriVariables);

// response extractor would be something like this
private String responseExtractor(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = response.getBody();
    ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    for (int length; (length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
        result.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    return result.toString("UTF-8");
}
```

This also bypasses ObjectMapper if your using Jackson and stringify invalid JSON.