# How I get RESTful response correctly?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-rest

I am consuming a restful with spring but I do not achieve get all data successfully.

RESTful response detail:

```
{
"errorCode": "0",
"errorMessage": "OK",
"transactionUUID": "2e48d6e7-f1fb-4271-b282-d74d3df1ef23",
"data":{
       "price": "123",
       "quantity" : "1",
       "productname" : "Anystuff"}
}
```

My classes:

```
public class ResponseRest{

     private String errorCode;
     private String errorMessage;
     private String transactionUUID;
     private ResponseDetail data;
     //get and set methods

}

public class ResponseDetail {

     private String price;
     private String quantity;
     private String productname;

     //get and set methods

}
```

Piece of my method in my controller class:

```
HttpHeader headers;
//headers.set....
String jsonParam = "{\"transactionToken\":\""+transactionToken+"\","
                  + "\"sessionToken\":\""+sessionToken+"\"}";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonParam, headers);
response = restTemplate.exchange(URL_API_AUTH, HttpMethod.POST, entity, ResponseRest.class);
```

When I got result by console, I only get the properties from the ResponseRest class but not their detail from class ResponseDetail, console result:

```
System.out.println("-> Result - status ("+ response.getStatusCode() + ") has body with: " + (response.getBody().toString()));
```

> Result - status (200) has body with: ResponseRest[errorCode="0", errorMessage="OK",transactionUUID="2e48d6e7-f1fb-4271-b282-d74d3df1ef23", data[price=null,quantity=null,productname=null]]

What I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for their time.

Comment: Please confirm there are get/setData(...) methods.  Where did that JSON response come from?  Are price and quantity really Strings?  Please confirm `data` is a single instance and not a list.

Comment: Yes, It's a json response from restful services and I already have set/get of data.

Comment: Price and quantity are been sending like string is right

Comment: is ResponseDetail a inner class or separate class?

Comment: Like separate class

Comment: try making `ResponseDetail implement Serializable`.  Actually make them both `implement Serializable`

Comment: @jiveturkey That doesn't have anything to do with this scenario.

Comment: Concerning the json response you posted, what is the origin?  Did you do something like this to [get the raw json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104149/spring-resttemplate-get-raw-json-string)?  Just to prove the json response really does match your class structure.

Comment: The RESTFul service have their guide, this one show this example of response. I think, is a probability that detail names from json have been changed but I am not sure

Comment: @AndrewS, I gotten the entire json with postForObject method in my case. Thanks everybody!