# How can I get data from a response after `RestTemplate` throws a `RestClientException` because it couldn't parse it

Tags: spring, exception, response, resttemplate

Using `restTemplate.exchange(uri, method, entity, responseType)` to make a REST call fails with a `RestClientException` when the response is of the wrong `responseType`. E.g.,

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [java.util.List<java.lang.Byte>] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8];
nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Numeric value (281759) out of range of Java byte
```

Since this is not a `RestClientResponseException` we don't seem to have access to the response data like status code and body (not even in their raw form).

Is there a way to get (raw) data from the original (unparsable) response? (for logging)

Comment: Hi, Did you tried  `getRawStatusCode()` & `getResponseBodyAsString()` as mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestClientResponseException.html#getRawStatusCode--) in spring doc,

Comment: Those are methods of `RestClientResponseException` but they are not available in `RestClientException`.

Comment: Ohhk, just read , _Since this is not a `RestClientResponseException`_ .
So you're looking for raw response (atleast) from the upstream server though `restTemplate`  failed to parse because of n reasons but one being like you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try parsing the response as `String`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104149/spring-resttemplate-get-raw-json-string) - the similar concept can be used with the `exchange` method.

**EDIT:** If the exception does not occur always and you still want to be able to map the correct responses easily, you could override the corresponding [`MessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/support/converter/MessageConverter.html) (which is actually throwing the exception) and do anything you want afterwards, because the converter gives you a raw `HttpInputMessage`.

Assuming you are using `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` it should look sth. like this *(not tested though)*:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper) {
        @Override
        public Object read(Type type, Class<?> contextClass, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
            try {
                return super.read(type, contextClass, inputMessage);
            } catch (HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
                // LOG here...
                throw e;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: But then I have to do the parsing into an object of the desired type myself? Does Spring offer that functionality?

Comment: Of course, but you asked for the raw response. Isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: The raw (String) data is fine if something goes wrong, since (in my case) it would be just for logging. But in the happy flow I would like to have the typed response body.

Comment: This means that if I want to have that information in the exceptional cases, I should always read the response as a String, and try to parse it myself into the expected response type. That way the String information is available if a parsing Exception occurs. But this means I have to do the parsing myself.

Comment: This seems like a way to go. The body of the `inputMessage` there is an `InputStream` so I have to cache it so I can actually read it a second time if something goes wrong. But I have access to everything I need here, without having to call the endpoint twice and still using the existing parsing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add StringHttpMessageConverter in RestTemplate's messageConverters

```
StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter
            = new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson2HttpMessageConverter
            = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(
            List.of(stringHttpMessageConverter, jackson2HttpMessageConverter));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        try { 
            restTemplate.exchange(uri, method, entity, responseType);
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            //for logging exact message
            restTemplate.getForObject("https://httpbin.org/ip", String.class); 

        }
```

Comment: This is just making the same call twice. Expensive operation.

Comment: Since in case of failure you need to call it again .

Comment: But what is the reason? I would think that the information is already retrieved so it is already on the client side. It's weird to log a response other than the one that actually caused the error. It's not always true that successive calls return the same info.

Comment: Since we don't the actual response type , we have two options to manually mapping the response after receiving /above

Comment: That is what your solution allows, but it's not the reason why your solution is necessary. I don't want to be making the same network call twice.