# How to access the name of a JSON object?

Tags: java, json, spring, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this JSON returned me from Firebase Realtime Database.

```
{
       "betslipid-4322": {
            "amount": 100,
            "bets": [
                {
                    "betType": "FT_RESULT_0",
                    "matchid": "ts-fb",
                    "odd": 2.4,
                    "status": "WAITING"
                }
            ],
            "status": "WAITING"
        },
        "betslipid-4323": {
            "amount": 7.5,
            "bets": [
                {
                    "betType": "FT_RESULT_2",
                    "matchid": "gs-fb",
                    "odd": 2.7,
                    "status": "WAITING"
                },
                {
                    "betType": "FT_RESULT_1",
                    "matchid": "gs-gb",
                    "odd": 1.3,
                    "status": "WAITING"
                }
            ],
            "status": "WAITING"
        }
}
```

I want to place the attributes of this JSON (including the betSlipID at the beginning) to the following Java class.

```
public class BetSlip {

    private List<Bet> bets;

    private Float amount;

    private BetStatus status;

    private betSlipID;
}
```

However, I was unable to access the betSlipIDs which are "betslipid-4322" and "betslipid-4323" in this case and I was also unable to convert the JSON to my java class by the following code.

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
List<BetSlip> betSlip = restTemplate.getForObject(getDatabaseLink("incomplete-betslips"), ArrayList.class);
```

Note that I don't know the betSlipIDs when I get the JSON response, so I can't create another class which includes a variable named the incoming betSlipID.

Comment: You can create a class which hold List<betSlips>. and map on that parent class

Comment: @Noshaf I already tried that but that doesn't help me getting betSlipIDs

Comment: let give try to HashMap<String,betSlips>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Noshaf 's comment here is the solution:

```
HashMap<String,BetSlip> betSlipWithoutID = restTemplate.getForObject(getDatabaseLink("incomplete-betslips"), HashMap.class);
```

After creating this HashMap, now there is a need for creating BetSlip class with betSlipID:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

BetSlip betSlip = mapper.convertValue(betSlipWithoutID.get(betSlipWithoutID.keySet().iterator().next()), BetSlip.class);

betSlip.setBetSlipID(betSlipWithoutID.keySet().iterator().next());
```

Here we go, betSlip is ready for use with a betSlipID attribute is set.

Answer (score 2):

I am not saying this is optimal, but you can follow this to do your task as your `betslipid-x` is variable, I am describing the steps to be followed only:

1. just return a json object from your `restTemplate` see [Spring restTemplate get raw json string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47104541/5332914)
2. get the keys applying `keySet()` on your returned json and you will get all your betslipid-x
3. based on that, get associated object of that key and deserialize in your `BetSlip` class and set the key as `betSlipID`.
4. Thus you get your desired object.

This should do your job.
Let me know if your need further clarification.

Comment: Thanks, this is almost exactly how I solved. I am accepting your answer but those needing code example of what you describe here can have a look at my answer.

Comment: that's right, theory here and code is in your answer :D !