# Spring Boot Get Api Response: Ebay API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ebay-api

I am trying to use Ebay API for testing purposes, but it looks like I am not getting the results I am trying to achieve.

I have this `@GetMapping` request in my controller as:

```
 @GetMapping(value = "test")
    public ResponseEntity testLogin(){

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        String findCompletedItemsUrl =  "https://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SECURITY-APPNAME=THIS-IS-MY-APP-ID&OPERATION-NAME=findCompletedItems&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&keywords=iphone%20case&categoryId=9355&sortOrder=PricePlusShippingLowest&itemFilter(0).name=Condition&itemFilter(0).value=1000&itemFilter(1).name=SoldItemsOnly&itemFilter(1).value=true&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=10&outputSelector(0)=SellerInfo&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US";

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(findCompletedItemsUrl, 
         String.class);
        return response;

    }
```

Please note the URL has a placeholder of APP ID. When I access the URL through the browser I get the following results:

```
{
  "findCompletedItemsResponse": [
    {
      "ack": [
        "Success"
      ],
      "version": [
        "1.13.0"
      ],
      "timestamp": [
        "2020-03-09T21:54:58.595Z"
      ],
      "searchResult": [
        {
          "@count": "1",
          "item": [
            {
              "itemId": [
                "174129065971"
              ],
              "title": [
                "For Apple iPhone 8 Plus Case Shock Absorption Cover Shockproof Bumper Rose"
              ],

       ...cut for brevity
        }
       ]
     }
```

But when I try to access the same URL using the above method, I get no results and the count property is showing 0. The json I get back is below:

```
{
  "findCompletedItemsResponse": [
    {
      "ack": [
        "Success"
      ],
      "version": [
        "1.13.0"
      ],
      "timestamp": [
        "2020-03-09T21:57:05.206Z"
      ],
      "searchResult": [
        {
          "@count": "0"
        }
      ],
      "paginationOutput": [
        {
          "pageNumber": [
            "0"
          ],
          "entriesPerPage": [
            "10"
          ],
          "totalPages": [
            "0"
          ],
          "totalEntries": [
            "0"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Not sure what I could be missing!

Comment: Did you check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104149/spring-resttemplate-get-raw-json-string

Answer (score 0):

Probably cookies of browser may impact on your result. So it can be reason of your different answers.